# Keep SubMenu display on hover blank space

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with an arrow I added, I want that when the user hovers to the submenu must remain display even if it passes the cursor on the white space, the problem is my class " .sub "must be "position: absolute", any idea?

sorry for my english XD

```css
 .color1:hover > div {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .sub{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: skewX(-15deg);
    background-color: rgba(237, 237, 237, 1);
    vertical-align: middle;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .globalList:hover .sub {
        display: block !important; 
    }
    .globalList > div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: skewX(-15deg);
    background-color: rgba(237, 237, 237, 1);
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
     .globalList:hover > div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 115px;
    margin-left: -74px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid rgba(157, 158, 159, 1);
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <ul class="MyList">
            <li class="globalList color1">
                <div>Menu1</div>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li class="Sub1"><div>Sublist1</div></li>
                    <li class="Sub2"><div>Sublist2</div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li>
                 <div>Menu2</div>
                 <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                 </ul>
            
             </li>
          </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `padding-bottom` to your **.globalList**.

Like this one:

```
.globalList{
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Or better:
(This is the same, but you must not add to each first **li** an `.globalList` class)

```
.MyList > li {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added a transparent box using `.sub:after` which will now allow you to let the mouse be between the main and submenu without closing the submenu. I assume that's what you mean with 'white space'.

```css
.color1:hover>div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  background-color: rgba(237, 237, 237, 1);
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.sub:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
}

.globalList:hover .sub {
  display: block !important;
}

.globalList>div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  background-color: rgba(237, 237, 237, 1);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.globalList:hover>div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 115px;
  margin-left: -74px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid rgba(157, 158, 159, 1);
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="MyList">
  <li class="globalList color1">
    <div>Menu1</div>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li class="Sub1">
        <div>Sublist1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="Sub2">
        <div>Sublist2</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Menu2</div>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```